# why does any contract i write to the blockchain look like this

Tags: remix, remix-tests

ive tried about 40 different contracts and they all do not show as a token, ive tried bsc,bsctestnet, pulsechain testnet.
when i try to verify the code on bscscan it says the byte code doesnt match
it also seems to not matter if i wait a long time,
this is an example of the code i am trying to commit.

thank you for your help in advanced.
https://github.com/TitanFinance/Token/tree/9fc23ebc5539e86758acb45ad27f895f33dc9066
i have tried nearly every one in this list with the same result, i have to be doing something wrong.
https://github.com/search?q=bep20+_taxFee+_liquidityFee&type=Code
i am following instructions here with a bit different process for multi file tokens. git clone the repository and uploading to remix.ethereum.org
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0cJz1kK3GmY

[image]

[image: contract]

Comment: Verfiying contract is always problem and no one will risk doing it for you :). are you using the correct compiler version? is optimization enabled? have you tried to use a plugin instead of trying to verify the contract directly on bsc etherscan?

Comment: Hi ryanolsen! Welcome to Ethereum Stackexchange! To be recognized as a token, it was needed for the contract to be verified and cause a Transfer event. Also usually in testnet it took longer to appear as a token (~24 hs).